# C++ calling C# COM interop error: HRESULT 0x80131509

Tags: c#, com, interop

I create a C# COM interop for c++ to invoke.
I have registered the dll and tlb file by regasm.
everything goes well till one day i changed code of C# part (i didn't change the definition of interface, just implementation changed). one interface in COM returns an error 0x80131509. the strange thing is, it is only happened in some computers (my develop PC is works well so i can't debug this problem).
I'm not really clear on how the C# COM worked with C++, after i registered them, i just know they create key value in window registry.(like what regasm /regfile generated). how c++ knows where the COM dll is(search path environment variables)? and what the use of tlb file in run time?

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is related to the registry... You should try to unregister and register (using regasm) your dll in the computers that are having this problem.

If that doesn't work unregister the dll in those computers, than use regedit to search and delete any missing registry keys that refer to it, after that register your dll again. You could also use one of those registry cleaner programs after deleting the missing keys to guarantee that you didn't miss anything.

Remember that you should allways register a dll in the directory that it will be used by your application and this should happen only once. If you need to unregister a dll, then you should allways do it in the same directory that you used for the registration. In other words, once a dll is registered **do not move it**.

Note: if your dll is not on the same path as your C++ application it should be in a directory that is referenced in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Today, i logged into the problem PC and finally find the reason why it goes wrong. it is because of C# COM part thrown an exception but i didn't catch it. the reason why i can't reproduce that is they are connect to difference database.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error as soon as I introduced a simple inheritance hierarchy to my COM library. A quick resolution was to **set the [ComVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to true on the base class**. This fixed my problem immediately.

It does make a lot of sense when you think about it - the compiler doesn't allow you to build a hierarchy where the base class is less visible than the inheriting class. So it being the same for COM should come as no surprise - the only difference being, that it is failing at run-time instead of compile-time.

I would venture that the true reason for the error is a broken constructor chain, but I put no further research into it.

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying to fix this for 6 hours! Had ComVisible set to false, and was getting 0x80131509, with null source code. Removed <Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(False)>, and it worked a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message when I was calling a .Net4 C# COM object from Visual FoxPro.

The method returns object, type of which may be one of several. All the types are derived from an abstract class which implemented an interface with the common stuff for these types.

Eventually I decided to remove the abstract-modifier from the base class and just make it public and ComVisible. This solved the problem for me, even though I would like the base class to be abstract.