# Class not registered when attempting to use Managed COM component in C++

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have created a C# assembly that exports a COM component. I am attempting to use it from C++ like so:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#import <mypath\WCFClient.tlb> named_guids raw_interfaces_only

using namespace WCFClient;

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    IWCFClientPtr pWCFClient;

    HRESULT hRes = pWCFClient.CreateInstance(CLSID_WCFCOMClient);
... etc ...
}
```

CreateInstance is returning `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered`.

1) My C# assembly is set to compile for x86, my C++ application is set to compile for Win32, although I have tried x64 on both as well.

2) I can see my CLSID HKCR\WOW6432Node\CLSID (or HKCR\CLSID when trying x64). The assembly information and path are correct.

3) The CLSID_WCFCOMClient in the generated .tlh file is correct. It is the CLSID I find in the registry.

I am running `regasm WCFClient.dll /codebase /tlb:WCFClient.tlb`, the appropriate one for the bitness I am compiling, before compiling the C++ application, although this is unnecessary as the C# project registers itself on build. It registers the appropriate bitness.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Are you using the correct regasm?  The one with the correct bitness and runtime for your compiled assembly?

Comment: Yes. To make things simple I am doing everything in x86 for now. I am running `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm`.

The assembly and the C++ application are both compiled for x86.

I can confirm the CLSID is in `HKCR\WOW6432Node\CLSID` and the information in the key is correct.

Comment: And you built against .NET runtime 4.0+?  I assume your class and constructor are declared public if it set the registry key....  I'd try deleting the registry key, and running regasm again.

Comment: Yes, NET 4.0. I have tried deleting the registry key. I have also tried using regasm -u before registering it again. Same result.

Comment: Get the same result running a VB script (.vbs) file from c:\windows\syswow64\wscript.exe that does something like set obj = CreateObject("YourProgId"), MsgBox TypeName(obj) ???

Comment: Error 0x80131509 when trying to CreateObject. Using the exact ProgId that is in HKCR\WOW6432Node\CLSID\...\ProgId.

Comment: That's a different error: #define UIA_E_INVALIDOPERATION       0x80131509 // COR_E_INVALIDOPERATION  Maybe an exception: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093531/c-calling-c-sharp-com-interop-error-hresult-0x80131509

I'd try debugging the .NET and setting a breakpoint in your class constructor.

Comment: That did it! The WCF endpoint my client connects to was in a config file that couldn't be found when run from the C++ application's context, so the COM object's constructor crashed when called from C++... and for some reason returned hresult Class not registered! That certainly is bizarre. You should submit as an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks a lot!